# Can't Remote Desktop To Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop, dns-server

I have just demoted our Windows Server 2012 Domain Controller. Removed all services, and then did a fresh install of Windows Server 2012 R2. I gave the server the same IP address and host name that it had previously. I have just promoted it to a DC again.
The problem I am having is that I can not remote desktop to the server using it's host name. I get the following error:

> Remote Desktop cannot verify the identity of the remote computer
>   because there is a time or date difference between your computer and
>   the remote computer. Make sure your computer's clock is set to the
>   correct time, and then try connecting again. If the problem occurs
>   again, contact your network administrator or the owner of the remote
>   computer.

I can assure you that the date, time (including AM/PM), and timezone are all correct on both the client and server. I have Googled this error and a lot of articles point to a DNS issue. However, DNS seems to be working fine on this server. Many clients are using this server as their DNS server without any issues. I can't find anything in event viewer either.

The only other far-fetched idea that I have is that when I demoted this DC something didn't get cleaned up properly, and it is still thinking that I am trying to remote into the old server. Although, I didn't get any errors when I demoted the DC.

Any help is appreciated.

> UPDATE

I failed to mentioned that this was a Virtual Machine. The time was off on the host itself. After I fixed the time, I could remote in via host name. However, I don't know how the server knew anything about the host. For all it knows, it is a physical machine. And it was using a centralized server for NTP. But hopefully this can help someone out in the future.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your workstation is storing connection data/certificate data for the old server and using it for the new server since they have the same hostname.

Navigate to HKEY_CU\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Servers.

Delete the key named the same as the server.

Comment: I have actually already tried this. I even tried from a machine that has never remoted into this server, and I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to this and close the loop, there's a good chance that your hypervisor has some sort of heartbeat/time synchronization setup and this is what is being synced(or is trying to sync) with the VM. If it's Hyper-V you can find the setting in Integration Services from Hyper-V manager.

I'm dealing with a similar situation where we lost power at one of our sites for some time and the Host time was off by 2 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Is there another DC, so that DNS can run? Or did you setup DNS already? Anyway, I'm assuming that you have a functioning DNS server.

Also assuming that you **can** RDP to the new server via IP.

Try running **ipconfig /flushdns** at a prompt line on the workstation, and then reboot.

Comment: Yes there is another DNS server. I have tried flushing dns and rebooting with no luck. I have also tried setting the server to use the other DNS server instead of itself.

Comment: Are you able to RDP to the server by its IP?

Comment: Yes. I found the problem. I updated the original post. Thanks for your help.